# Clojure - Convert data from one form to another

Tags: clojure

I want to convert the following data:

```
({"name" "databases", "columns" ["name"], "values" [["testdb"] ["mydb"]]})
```

into

```
({:name "testdb"} {:name "mydb"})
```

I am unable to figure how can i do this neatly in a clojure way.

Comment: I don't see the point in the downvotes and lock. This is a question like many others that have been asked here. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to make multiple maps all with the same keys, partially applying [`zipmap`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/zipmap/) works pretty neatly:

```
(defn to-maps [{:strs [columns values]}]
  (map (partial zipmap (map keyword columns)) values))
```

Examples:

```
(to-maps {"name" "databases", "columns" ["name"], "values" [["testdb"] ["mydb"]]})
;;=> ({:name "testdb"} {:name "mydb"})

(to-maps {"name" "databases",
          "columns" ["name", "connectionstring"],
          "values" [["testdb", "foo"] ["mydb", "bar"]]})
;;=> ({:connectionstring "foo", :name "testdb"} {:connectionstring "bar", :name "mydb"})
```